# Redirect to login page asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a site made in asp.net (vb.net as backend).
This site is locateted http://localhost/TEST.
If I visit any aspx file like http://localhost/TEST/about.aspx i get redirected to login aspx. Login.aspx is set as start page in visual studio.

The problem is that if i visit http://localhost/TEST I come to a directory with a list of all the aspx files.

How do I redirect any user that visit http://localhost/TEST to http://localhost/TEST/login.aspx ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your post has some mixed concepts in it.  Lets get them organized.

First, VS has a start page.  That is the starting page used when you run the web site with or without the debugger.  That only matters when you are running the site from VS.  Once you deploy to IIS then that no longer has any impact.

What you are asking for is a default page the user is redirected to when they don't explicitly specify a page.  You can configure the default page in the web.config like this:

```
<system.webServer>
  <defaultDocument>
    <files>
      <clear />
      <add value="About.aspx" />
    </files>
  </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

You don't want to specify Login.aspx as the default page.  Specify a home page.  If the user has already logged in then they should not be automatically navigated to the login page, you want them to go to some home page.

The login page sounds like it is already configured correctly because you mentioned that when you go to about.aspx it redirect to login.aspx.  That is handled in the authentication section of the web.config file.  If the user has not been authenticated then it will redirect to the login page.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms name="asp.ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" path="/"/>
</authentication>
```

I think the only part you need to change is adding the defaultDocument section to web.config.

Answer (score 1):

In your folder **TEST**, create a blank webpage called "default.aspx" that redirects visitors to the login page if they are not logged in or the about page if they are logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `web.config` file and disable the directory browsing.

```
<system.webServer>
  <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
</system.webServer>
```